# How exactly would SOPA-style DNS blocking threaten the security of the Internet?

Tags: dns, dnssec

A point that keeps getting mentioned in the SOPA debate is that the DNS blocking it prescribes will cause security problems. Can somebody explain in simple terms just exactly how SOPA threatens Internet security?

Comment: +1 -- good question for something has been an important recent discussion. This is clear, relevant in the future, and directly answerable.

Answer (score 5):

The main security-related concerns raised so far are

- attackers may use false infringement claims as a denial-of-service attack.
- ISPs may start doing deep packet inspection on their customer's traffic, to look for infringing content.
- it may interfere with the effectiveness of, or take-up of, DNSSEC.